# How do I plot values from a struct as different lines so I can control their color Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, structure, legend

#### What I want:

Different coloured points on a plot and to have the points in a legend with their respective colours.

#### I tried this:

I have created a struct which contains x, y values of points. With these points I hope to plot points on an image so I can see where they are. However, as I'm using a struct I can't get the plot to make the points in different colours. With the for loop I tried to coax matlab in creating multiple plots, and hopefully different lines, which I could then assign to different colours of my choosing.

Code:

```
img = imread('retinotopische map V1M Base clean.bmp');            

hold on;                     
image([0.825 4.61],[-2.85 ,-8.25],img);

for A =  1:B
    plot( [c(A).Lateral],[c(A).Bregma],'o','MarkerSize',10);    
    plot( [c(A).Lateral],[c(A).Bregma],'.','MarkerSize',10);    
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colour using the 'Color' option:

```
   img = imread('retinotopische map V1M Base clean.bmp');            

    hold on;                     
    image([0.825 4.61],[-2.85 ,-8.25],img);

    for A =  1:B
       plot( [c(A).Lateral],[c(A).Bregma],'o','MarkerSize',10, 'Color', [A/B, 0, 1 - A/B]);     
    end
```

'Color' lets you specify an [RGB triple](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html) like [1 0 0] for red for example. You can use this to plot whatever colors you want. My example will plot them in like a gradient but you could also have totally different colours using say `rand(1, 3)` to get the triple? Or else make a colour matrix where you specify the exact order of colours you want like:

```
MyColours = [1 1 0;
             0 0 1;
             1 0 0;
             0.5 0.2 0.9]; %etc...
```

and then in your for loop:

```
plot( [c(A).Lateral],[c(A).Bregma],'o','MarkerSize',10, 'Color', MyColours(A, :));
```

Comment: This solves all my problems exactly, and also gives me consistency over other plots I wish to make. Thanks ever such a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want different colors, the solution is easier than you would expect:

Replace `hold on` with `hold all` and matlab will automatically use the next color.

Edit: If you start a new plot, you may need to call `hold off` and `hold all` again to get the right starting position.

Comment: I was not aware of this. +1

Comment: @Maximinium Could you explain the problem a bit more? Perhaps with a screenshot or a clear description of 'order' and 'correspond'?
Also see my edit.

Comment: Here is my code for the plot builder, I took it out of the larger code for legibility:  [Img](http://snag.gy/spQUb.jpg). So What i want is what you can see on the left of the image. I want two plots which mark two sets of coordinates. Where the color corresponds to an electrode. Furthermore the legend needs to say electrode 1 ..2 etc. So the order is the order of the electrodes and with correspond i mean that the yellow point in fig1 3,-5 has to correspond with a yellow point in fig2 being 50,-30. And the colour corresponds with a unique electrode. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Now all I'm Trying to figure out is how to get the legends to work.